# Menu dropdown messed up after translating page using Google translator

Tags: translation, google-translate, drop-down-menu, code-translation, google-translator-toolkit

My menu drop-down is now messed up, after I translated the page using on-the-fly Google translater. It refuses to recognize CSS classes I have created and used for exclusion (e.g, I have a class like this `class="notranslate"`, which is no no longer working).

For demostration purpose, I have source code
[here](http://www.brightkity.net)

*Note: Must register to the site first. Any help would be appreciate it. Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going on but look at this tool: [Translate This](http://www.translateth.is/)

This uses the Google Translate but is easier to use.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just Added <br/> and everything working right now.

Comment: Good, make sure you are aware of this though: The Google Translate API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. Due to the substantial economic burden caused by extensive abuse, the number of requests you may make per day will be limited and the API will be shut off completely on December 1, 2011. For website translations, we encourage you to use the Google Translate Element. (not sure if you are using that or the API) just a FYI